# Easiest way to get 36 -12V sources?

Tags: power-supply, led, shift-register

I'm using the SN74HC595 to drive 36 LEDs (industrial, with internal current limiting), except the LEDs (which aren't substitutable) are common-anode, so I'm using 36 MOSFETs to handle that, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmOt39.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem becomes how to get those 36 -12V supplies, without increased load on one LED reducing the power available for the others. Any ideas?

Comment: LED series resistors for current limiting would be a start - then they won't go bang.

Comment: @TonyM They're built into the industrial-strength LEDs I'm using, but I appreciate the sentiment

Comment: What do you mean by "common cathode"?  Your schematic shows independent LEDs - neither common anode or common cathode, and you are switching the cathodes.

Comment: The schematic still shows common anode.

Comment: Why not use one 12 V source capable of driving all 36 channels?

Comment: 9 questions asked previously and no answer accepted. That seems unlikely as you are still here asking questions so, are all the answers given previously all wrong or have one or two (or maybe more or most) of your questions received at least one decent answer that could be formally accepted? That's the currency in these parts - nobody here asks for money but folk do expect some payment now and then. Please correct your schematic to match the words in the question.

Comment: @Andyaka I tend to get excellent answers months or years after asking, so I'm very generous with upvotes, and very conservative with accepting answers

Comment: @HandyHowie Slip of the fingers. I thought I typed common-anode

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist: (1) Why are there a voltage sources at the source of each MOSFET? What was your intention? (2) Note that if you assign a negative voltage to a voltage source (like in V10..V17) the positive terminal is where the negative sign is and the negative terminal is where the plus sign is. Did you really mean that? If not you should correct the schematic.

Comment: @Curd The goal is to independently drive the LEDs of this common-anode LED module. Because the LEDs share an anode, the only way to ensure each LED has adequate voltage is to supply a voltage sink of the precise 12 volts it needs independent of the others. I'm trying to figure out how to get this set of independent negative voltage sources when they all ultimately draw from a single mains outlet.

Comment: Use one properly sized 12V supply that is rated for more current than all of your LEDs together will draw.  Problem solved.

Comment: Where does this idea of using one -12V supply for each led come from? Are you aware that you need some level shifting between the 74HC595 and the FETs if you do that? Because as it is, the FETs won't ever turn off (unless the GND of the 595 also lies at -12V). Why don't you use a 24V supply instead of +12 / -12 anyway?

Answer (score 14):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzdvz7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Modified schematic.*

> The problem becomes how to get those 36 12V supplies, without increased load on one LED reducing the power available for the others.

Figure 1 shows the normal method of achieving your goal. A common 12 V supply is used for all the (12 V) LED lamps. M1 - M8 provide a switchable return path to the power supply. Provided V1 is stabilised and has enough current capacity then there will be no interaction between the LEDs.

Comment: .. although you should also have a bit of current limiting capability in there as well, even if it's just a 1 ohm power resistor on each LED.

Comment: According to the OP they're 12 V LED lights. S/he has buried this information in the comments somewhere. Thanks.